# Most efficient means of getting water from an aquifer

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

On my present embark I have a VERY small bit of light aquifer. I want to try and set up an obsidian farm, but as small as the aquifer is I'm unsure if it'll provide enough water for my purposes. I'm thinking a checkered pattern of grates and aquifer squares, with the room below completely dug out as a reservoir.

[image: Offset so no two aquifer tiles leak into the same space]

Is a checkboard ideal? Would it be better to have an offset grid such as the image above? Is there another pattern? I could use that will produce more water?

Comment: According to the wiki, a tile will also fill with water if it is below aquifer-stone (but not above), so the true ideal structure would be 3 dimensional. I have no idea what this would look like - and I don't know how feasible it really is, given that you can't directly see which squares are aquifers. Personally, I'd just mine out the bottom layer and let water trickle down, and focus on designing a reservoir that minimizes evaporation.